# Creating a tree from a list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tree

I seem to be blind at the moment, so I need to ask here. I want to sort a list of tuples which look like that

```
(id, parent_id, value)
```

So that it is a representation of the tree as a flattend list of list of tree nodes.

For example the input

```
(1, None, '...')
(3, 2', '...')
(2, 1, '...')
(4, 1, '...')
(5, 2, '...')
(6, None, '...')
```

Should sorted like that afterwards

```
(1, None, '...')
(2, 1, '...')
(3, 2', '...')
(5, 2, '...')
(4, 1, '...')
(6, None, '...')
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of tree? What have you tried so far? ... why not just use a current implementation?

Comment: What kind of sort is that? It's a lopsided tree with more than one root node? I'm confused.

Comment: Basically, I get this from a database. What kind of tree can't be termined, cause it is nicer balanced or anything like that. It is more like a filesystem tree. And what do you mean by a current implementation?

Comment: This is a list of parent-child relation ships, which I want to order to display inside a tree or something like that on a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python sorts tuples from left to right, so if you arrange your tuples so the first sort key is the first item and so forth, it'll be reasonably efficient.

The mapping from a list of tuples to a tree is not clear from what you're describing.  Please draw it out, or explain it more thoroughly.  For example, your example appears to be:

[image: tree diagram]
<sub>(source: [sabi.net](http://web.sabi.net/temp/tree.png))</sub>

If you've got two nodes with no parent, that is more like a forest than a tree.  What are you trying to represent with the tree?  What does "sorted" mean in this context?

Comment: Yes, essentially it is a forest of trees. Every tuple in the list is an item, that can have another tuple as its parent. Your picture models it correctly. It is comparable to a filesystem view, what I want to create.

Comment: OK, so how do you want to sort the forest?  It looks like you're doing more or less a preorder traversal, then sorting the roots by ID?  If so, I'd suggest you  consider using another representation that makes them easier to sort, for example nested dictionaries whose keys are the node IDs.  Then you can flatten the dictionaries into the list of tuples representation, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've quite follows what you are exactly trying to do, but if you have a forest as a list of nodes, can't you just read it and build the tree structure, then write it out as a bread-first traversal of all the trees?  Any particular reason to avoid this?

Comment: No, I think, I will have to take this approach. The only thing I wanted to skip was the possible situation, where I have a list of 10.000 tuples (aka database rows), which I put into a dictionary base forest and from which I create a list of tuples again.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver, if I understand correctly, I think you can either
(a) retrieve all tuples from your database into a dictionary or list, and then construct the tree, 
OR
(b) use an ORDER BY clause when you retrieve the tuples so that they are in the order in which you will add them to the tree.

If changes to the tree may be made in your application and then propagated to the database, I would opt for a, but if changes are always made as database inserts, updates or deletes, and apart from these your tree is read-only, then option b should be faster and require less resources.

Roland